# Why contract owner suddenly has bunch of zeros as prefix?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, upgrading, foundry, forge

I am making upgradeable erc20 smart contract using *chugsplash* as upgrader and foundry as framework. It's name is **FractionToken.sol** and has it test contract **FractionToken.t.sol.**

It went well(The contract deployed successfully and the test ran successfully) before I implement the *chugsplash* to the contract.

**FYI: I am new both to smart contract and using *chugsplash***

when implementing the *chugsplash* to **FractionToken.sol** and did some corrections to how the contract(**FractionToken.sol**) constructor defined, eventually It's deployed using *chugsplash* successfully in localhost using anvil.

[image: successfully deploy upgradeable smart contract locally]

But, the problem now is in Testing, on of the problem is, functions that were defined in **FractionToken.sol** that has onlyOwner modifier, now reverts with error (**[FAIL. Reason: Ownable: caller is not the owner]**). So I tried to debug, in **FractionToken.t.sol**,

in FrractionToken.t.sol:

```
contract FractionTokenTest is Test {
    FractionToken fractionToken;

function setUp() public virtual {
        // Create a ChugSplash instance
        ChugSplash chugsplash = new ChugSplash();

        // Define the path from the project root to your ChugSplash file.
        string memory chugsplashFilePath = "./chugsplash/hello-chugsplash.json";

        // Deploy all contracts in your ChugSplash file
        chugsplash.deploy(chugsplashFilePath, true);

        // You *must* refresh EVM state after calling `chugsplash.deploy`.
        chugsplash.refresh();

        fractionToken = FractionToken(
            payable(
                chugsplash.getAddress(chugsplashFilePath, "<MY SC REFERENCE NAME>")
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And on of the tests, I consolelog:

```
console2.logAddress(address(fractionToken)); 
// returns 0x7Fdfb1eF01b5B4bC59F5D7FF2530f2dC4E1889E6

console2.logAddress(fractionToken.getOwner());
//returns 0x0000000000000000000000007fdfb1ef01b5b4bc59f5d7ff2530f2dc4e1889e6
```

Why they return basically the same address only that the other has "0x000000000000000000000000" as prefix and this made the test reverted with error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here

The return data seems to be 32-byte, are you using `bytes32` type to store the address instead of `address` type?

Comment: Thank you for your respond. No, I didn't. I used address type.

Comment: Intersting. Could you paste your fractionToken.sol here?